# On click for list view flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, onclick

Hi I am new to the flutter I have created a list view in flutter using dart. code is below

```
List<Container> _buildListItemsfromFlower() {
    return flowers.map((flowers) {
      var container = Container(
          child: new Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: new Text(flowers.flowerName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: 25,
                )),
          ),
          new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
            child: new Text(flowers.description,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none)),
          ),
          new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(55, 0, 0, 15),
            child: new Image.asset(flowers.imageurl),
            width: 70.0,
            height: 70.0,
          )
        ],
      ));
      return container;
    }).toList();
```

How to add on Click for list view for the above code ?

Comment: do you want to be able to click all the items inside the listview or the Container?

Comment: Wrap your List with `GestureDetector` widget with this widget you can able to click any widget

Comment: @Uni yes. when I wrapped it with FlatButton strted to work.

Comment: Don't wrap your Container with FlatButton. Wrap it with Inkwell or GestureDetector

Comment: @Uni what is the difference FlatButton and GestureDetector ?

Comment: FlatButton creates a button and padding around its child. GestureDetector is like a button with more functionalities (it can detect press, long press, double tap,etc.) and it doesn't create padding around its child. An InkWell is like a GestureDetector but it makes a splash effect when you press it.

Comment: @Uni thank you for that information. Now I am using GestureDetector as FlatButton taking padding. Not the list view is full screen. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your container with any button like InkWell or FlatButton or RaiseButton. For ex-

```
List<Container> _buildListItemsfromFlower() {
    return flowers.map((flowers) {
      var container = Container(
          child: new Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: new Text(flowers.flowerName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: 25,
                )),
          ),
          new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
            child: new Text(flowers.description,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none)),
          ),
          new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(55, 0, 0, 15),
            child: new Image.asset(flowers.imageurl),
            width: 70.0,
            height: 70.0,
          )
        ],
      ));
      return FlatButton(
                    child: container,
                    onPressed: (){
                      //run your command here
                    },
                  );
    }).toList();
```

Here is another example-

```
return InkWell(
          child: container,
          onTap: () {
           // your command
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Hi yash thanks for your reply can u please explain me how to wrap it